React, How to add sitemap.xml to my website?
I have a sitemap.xml file I want to show it when users hit www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml route. How can I do that? I am using react and react-router-dom.
I know there is option to jsut add the sitemap.xml file to public directory but I dont have public directory, only src directory and its not make www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml
bottom line:
I have a sitemap.xml file inside my src directory, and this is the staticwebapp.config.json:
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/admin",
      "allowedRoles": ["administrator"]
    },
    {
      "route": "/sitemap.xml",
      "staticDir": "src"
    }
  ],
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["/assets/*.{png,jpg,gif,ico,svg,css,js}"]
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json",
    ".xml": "application/xml"
  }

What I'm missing? I think its should to work already...
